# Comment style: Imperative or third person

Tags: coding-style, comments

I have a question relating programming and english language both: Whether to use third person or imperative when commenting single lines of code.
Assume following line of code in a imperative language which should be commented:

```
object.doSomething();
```

My approach to comment this line would be to put the comment behind it using third person like this would be a ordinary english sentence containing the line as subject:

```
object.doSomething(); // does (referencing to the line of code) some action
```

But since we are in a imperative language and thus actually "commanding" the computer, one could even think of putting the comment before the code and using imperative:

```
//Do some action:
object.doSomething();
```

This is even useful when one need to comment multiple lines related to each other.

I personally prefer the first style but i often feel unsure about what style to use. It would be great if some could write their personal experience down here.

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Comments should not be a rephrasing of code. There are entire books dedicated to code readability.

Comment: If you need to comment about the intent of code at line level and it isn't machine code, you got way more problems than verb tense! My personal experience is that people who institute insane commenting practices, never maintain the comments....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I kept the examples simple in order to improve abstraction and readability of this question. I don't assume comments to rephrasing code like they do here but to go into detail.   Where would be the right place to ask?; i don't see the english forum from StackExchange fitting because in my opinion this question is heavily related to coding.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ features a number of questions on coding style.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, [search under their coding-style tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=[coding-style]+comment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first approach is definitely the more appropriate method of commenting, as it will be people reading your comments it is important that they are as easy to read as is possible. `//Do something`sounds like you are talking to the computer as opposed to explaining what the code does.

Comment: I disagree 100% with this answer. The second form is more concise, and is equally easier to understand. Also, when you are programming you are indeed giving instructions to the computer, for me, the comments reflect this as well.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez-Saez but the documentation is text that talks about the code itself, not a rearrangement of the code in natural language. At least in my opinion, a docstring should answer the first question a developer has when looking at a piece of code: "What does this do?"

Answer (score 39):

Oracle's official style guide states:

> **Use 3rd person (descriptive) not 2nd person (prescriptive). 
>   The description is in 3rd person declarative rather than 2nd person     imperative.**
>
> Gets the label. (preferred)
>
> Get the label. (avoid)

Oracle's style guide can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html#styleguide).

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Comment: The question was about _single lines of code_, not about functions. In Java, Javadoc strings are not attached to single lines of code.

Answer (score 28):

For Python, [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) states about docstrings (emphasis added):

> The docstring is a phrase ending in a period. It prescribes the function or
>   method's effect *as a command* ("Do this", "Return that"), *not as a description*;
>   e.g. don't write "Returns the pathname ...".

And [PEP257: Good Python docstring by example](https://blog.dolphm.com/pep257-good-python-docstrings-by-example/) is even more explicit (emphasis added):

> Note that all docstrings begin with a one-line summary. The summary is
>   written in the *imperative mood* ("do", "use", "find", "return", "render",
>   etc) and ends with a period.

Comment: The question was about _single lines of code_, not about functions. In Python, docstrings are not attached to single lines of code.

Answer (score 9):

Google has clear directives making a distinction between documentation targeted at implementers of an interface (explain what to do, imperative style) and documentation targeted at users of a library (explain what it does, third person style), which is your case.

Admittedly this distinction makes little sense for line-level comments, which always explain what the code does.

In other words, it's 3rd person for me.

https://developers.google.com/style/reference-verbs

Answer (score 7):

I think the most common pattern I have seen is to use third person when describing classes, methods and functions definitions, and imperative mood when commenting pieces of code, function calls etc.

So when you have a comment on top of a function definition, you are describing what the function does. So you use "Creates foo" rather than "Create foo"

```
// Creates a Foo object
function create_foo() {
// ...
}
```

Then if you *need* to describe a function call, use imperative mood.

```
// Create a Foo object
create_foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Conventional commits use [`imperative present tense`](https://github.com/conventional-commits/conventionalcommits.org/blob/master/content/next/index.md#what-writing-form-should-i-use)

> What writing form should I use?
>
> We recommend writing a commit description and body using the [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) present tense writing form.
>
> There are a significant number of examples of this writing form for commits [1](https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) [2](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/22b96b9/CONTRIBUTING.md#subject) [3](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project) [4](https://medium.com/@danielfeelfine/commit-verbs-101-why-i-like-to-use-this-and-why-you-should-also-like-it-d3ed2689ef70) [5](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/)

Similarly to [Python](https://blog.dolphm.com/pep257-good-python-docstrings-by-example/) using imperative mood in docstring in answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54868794/899047)

Comment: The question is not about Git